# WFA won't open on other computers

Tags: vb.net

I recently programmed a Windows Form Application on one laptop, however, when I attempt to run the executable on my client's PC it won't open. There are no error messages generated, it just won't open.

The only thing in use that wasn't built into VS2015 was Telerik UI for winforms and the application is a standalone exe.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to add information that might make it possible for us to help. You could start by telling us what WFA is. It would also help if you describe the components of your application (just an exe, or exe + dlls, any other required files) and how you installed the files on the client's PC.

Comment: You  likely forgot to include a dependency, such as an assembly that is needed by your application, a path configuration, or any million of other things. We are not psychic here. You need to include relevant information that would allow someone to at least guess at a possible or probable cause. Please [edit] your question after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I've editted the question, didn't know what information needed to be included, my apologies

Comment: Does it use a database? What is the OS on your laptop? What was the compilation target (32 bit, 64, ... processor architecture) ? What does your configuration file look like? What file paths does it depend on? What is your client's PC, what OS is it running, what account was used to install it? Is that user account? ... there are a million potentially important aspects that you could check. A general statement like "App works on PC 1 but not on PC 2" is not helpful in determining why.

Comment: You say that you used Telerik UI for Windows Forms, but then you say your application is a standalone exe. Are you sure that the Telerik product isn't a dll that you are referencing and that will therefore need to be installed with your application?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, how would I check for this just to be certain? Sorry, this is my first serious project, so still learning

Comment: @JamesHughes: I'm not familiar with Telerik UI for WinForms, but I would be surprised if it doesn't require at least one dll that was provided by Telerik. What did you have to do in order to make Telerik UI for WinForms part of your project?

Comment: I installed the Telerik software (just a normal exe installer) and that added the components to the visual studios toolbox and I added them from there

Comment: @JamesHughes: Look in the bin\release folder of your project. In addition to your exe file (and probably a pdb and an xlm file), is there a dll? If so, that dll is required for your application to work.

Comment: The only files in there are .exe, .config, .pdb, .vshost.exe and xml

Comment: The Telerik components may be installed in the Global Assembly Cache and therefore may not appear in the bin folder.  You should refer to the Telerik documentation on how to deploy applications that use their product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this sorted a couple of days ago. After a LOT of fiddling about I realised that it was indeed to do with the references. After consulting the Telerik Documentation (as Chris suggested) I realised that, indeed, the dlls were stored in the GAC (something I'd never heard of) and not actually automatically packaged with the software. So I editted the program file options so that they were included and problem solved! Thank You all for your help and sorry the original question was so badly written, I had no idea what data it would have been relevant to include